# Semantics Equivalence of Structural Semantics of While Programming Language

Tags: programming-languages, types-and-programming-languages, operational-semantics

I'm taking a course about the formality of programming languages and while reading Semantics with Applications: An Appetizer by H.R Nielson and F. Nielson
I came across the following exercise:
[image]

I'm referring to the last statement - I managed to proof that the statement is semantically equivalent using the Natural Operational Semantics but failed to prove using Structural Operational Semantics.

**EDIT:**
This is the sense the exercise refers to
[image]

Comment: Please clarify what "in the sense above" means exactly. What have you tried?

Comment: I added the sense. So far I tried to use the derivation sequences to deduce that S1, S2 and S3 all have derivation sequences and than use those to compose a derivation tree for S1;(S2;S3) but with no success